# Google drive API en android - traer una imagen en base a su DriveId

Tags: java, android, google-drive

buen día, estoy trabajando con la API de google drive en android, y encontré el siguiente código para leer un archivo de texto:

```
private void readFile(DriveId fileDriveId) {

        DriveFile file = fileDriveId.asDriveFile();

        file.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Log.e(TAG,"Error al abrir fichero (readFile)");
                            return;
                        }

                        DriveContents contents = result.getDriveContents();

                        BufferedReader reader =
                                new BufferedReader(
                                        new InputStreamReader(contents.getInputStream()));

                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        try {
                            String line;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                builder.append(line);
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG,"Error al leer fichero");
                        }

                        contents.discard(mGoogleApiClient);

                        Log.i(TAG, "Fichero leido: " + builder.toString());
                    }
                });
    }
```

el código lo probé y funciona, pero lo que yo necesito hacer, es que, **en vez de leer un archivo de texto, el código me devuelva el bitmap de la imagen que deseo recuperar**

**¿Cómo podría realizar eso?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la respuesta, el método queda de la siguiente manera:

```
private void readFile(DriveId fileDriveId) {

        DriveFile file = fileDriveId.asDriveFile();
        file.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Log.e(TAG,"Error al abrir fichero (readFile)");
                            return;
                        }

                        DriveContents contents = result.getDriveContents();

                        //BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(contents.getInputStream()));
                        Bitmap bmap = null;
                        InputStream is = contents.getInputStream();
                        bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                        imgPrueba.setImageBitmap(bmap);
                        /*StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        try {
                            String line;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                builder.append(line);
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG,"Error al leer fichero");
                        }*/

                        contents.discard(mGoogleApiClient);

                        //Log.i(TAG, "Fichero leido: " + builder.toString());
                    }
                });
    }
```

Dejé a propósito el código original para que sepan que fué lo que modifiqué, un saludo!